# Simplify Boolean statements (Java)

Tags: java, boolean, expression

I am trying to simplify the following `boolean` expressions. However, I can't figure them out. I would like to know how to get to the answer. Where `b` is a `boolean and`n`is an`int`

```
A. if (n==0) {b=true;} else {b=false;} // is it  b=!n; ????
B. if (n==0) {b=false;} else {b=true;}
C. b = false; if (n>1) {if (n<2) {b=true;}}
D. if (n<1) {b=true;} else {b=n>2;}
```

I also  tried to simplify the expressions; is this correct?

```
b==true      // b
b==false     // !b
b!=true      // !b
b!=false     // b
```

Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure what it is you're trying to do, but it may be helpful to note that in Java, `int n` is not a boolean expression, but `(n==0)` is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. `b = n == 0;`

B. `b = n != 0;`

C.  `b = n > 1 && n < 2;`

D. `b = n < 1 || n > 2;`

Answer (score 3):

> A.
>
> ```
> if (n==0) {b=true;} else {b=false;}
> ```

```
b = (n == 0);
```

> B.
>
> ```
> if (n==0) {b=false;} else {b=true;}
> ```

```
b = (n != 0);
```

> C.
>
> ```
> b = false; if (n>1) {if (n<2) {b=true;}}
> ```

```
b = false; // No int is > 1 and < 2.
```

> D.
>
> ```
> if (n<1) {b=true;} else {b=n>2;}
> ```

```
b = n < 1 || n > 2;
```